# Meteor, Blaze: create a simple loop with each?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

A simple problem, but I can`t find the simple solution. Did I have to write a helper for that?

I want to create a specific amount of li items in a template. The concrete number is given through a parameter called max.

```
{{> rating max=10 value=rating }}

<template name="rating">
    <ul class="rating">
        {{#each ?}}
            <li  class="star">\u2605</li>
        {{/each }}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307531/how-can-i-repeat-a-block-n-times-in-a-meteor-spacebars-template

Comment: Not really. That's a complicated variant of the obvious solution to create a array in onCreated. I am looking for something like ng-repeat in angular.

Answer (score 4):

Im fine with:

```
Template.registerHelper('repeat', function(max) {
    return _.range(max); // undescore.js but every range impl would work
});
```

and

```
{#each (repeat 10)}}
    <span>{{this}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: By replacing the register helper by `Template.registerHelper('repeat', function() {
  let args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  args.splice(-1,1);
  return _.range.apply(this, args);
})` you will be able to use `repeat max`, `repeat start end` and `repeat start end step`

Comment: `return _.range(1, max + 1);` for non-zero based array

Answer (score 2):

From http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_each:

> Constructs a View that renders contentFunc for each item in a
>   sequence.

So each must be used with a sequence (array,cursor), so you have to create a helper that create a sequence to use #each.
Usually view is customized by item value, but in your case an array with `max` size will do the job.

Or you can create a custom template helper where you can pass html to repeat and number of repetition and concat html in helper.
Something like(code not tested):

```
// Register helper
htmlRepeater = function (html,n) {
   var out = '';
   for(var i=0 ; i<n;i++) 
       out.contat(html);
   return  Spacebars.SafeString(out);
};

Template.registerHelper('repeat', htmlRepeater);
------------------------
// in template.html
{{{repeat  '<li  class="star">\u2605</li>' max}}}
```

Comment: But that sounds bad. Create an array to iterate a specific amount of times. Is there no better solution?

Comment: That seems it to be. Strange that this is not build in.

Comment: Meteor focus db, sometimes it's a limitation, but the rest of time it's wonderful:)

Answer (score 0):

Simply return the required number of items from the underlying helper:

html:

```
{{> rating max=10 value=rating }}

<template name="rating">
    <ul class="rating">
        {{#each myThings max}}
            <li class="star">\u2605</li>
        {{/each }}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Note that `max` needs to be passed through the html template to the `{{#each}}`

js:

```
Template.rating.helpers({
  myThings: function(max){
    // return an array 0...max-1 (as convenient as any other set of values for this example)
    return Array.apply(null, Array(max)).map(function (x, i) { return i; });
  }
});
```

Of course if you were iterating over a collection then you could just limit your `.find()` to `max`.

I also notice your `rating` template isn't using the parameter `value` anywhere. Did you mean to do:

```
<ul class = "{{value}}">
```

or was the value supposed to be substituted elsewhere?